# Trying to use jquery .slideDown() with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use .slideDown() with multiple classes, but i want only one at a time to toggle/dropdown!
Because if i run my code currently and i press the button, it will make them all show, instead of only the one i want to show!
How can i do that?

my html:

```
    <!doctype HTML>
<head>
    <title>Ricoz.co.uk Rp Directory</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script rel="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar"></div>
    <div class="char">
    <div class="picture"></div>
    <div class="text">
    here is some text!</div>
    <button>test</button>
    </div>
    <div class="char">
    <div class="picture"></div>
    <div class="text">
    here is some text!</div>
    <button>test</button>
    </div>


</body>
```

My Css:

```
body{
    background-image: url(tb.jpg);
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px
}
.navbar{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
}
.row{
    height: 440px;

}
.char{
/*  border-radius: 20px; */
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px; 
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;

}
.char  > .picture{
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 200px;
}
.text{
    width:200px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

JavaScript/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text').hide();
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('.text').slideToggle();

    });
});
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Ricoz, did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text').hide();
    $(this).click(function(event){
        $(event.target).prev().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

This will choose previous element (related to the button that was clicker -> so your text that you want to show), but only one (above clicked button). Previously you were referencing all elements with class .text so it wasn't working the way you want.

[Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) contains target property - the button that was clicked and you can use it to get previous element using [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method. Then you can trigger sliding animation.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0j85uarz/)

Also I'd modify you selector from

```
$(this).click(...)
```

to

```
$('button').click(...)
```

since you want to target only buttons. Even better if you add class to those buttons like .click-button and then reference them via

```
$('button.click-button').click(...)
```

in case you might want to have some buttons without that effect.

Comment: Would likely be smart to change to a selector that is more relevant to the targets instead of using `this` which is `document`

Comment: @charlietfl Funny, I've thought the same and suggested it just now.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but i've already changed the code and the page slightly. I hope the code might still help others.